# Issue with cURL command in windows

Tags: windows, azure, curl, cmd, access-token

I'm using this below curl command to get the access token for azure in windows but it is giving me error. Can any one please help ?

```
curl -X POST \ -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=5f4b3vd93-6440-4867-92c3-fffb872db68e&client_secret=oChfk2/MaiN8MSdl2DycRIxqskU4JNV++RSC+nR1U="&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F' \ https://login.microsoftonline.com/6ac7a1f4-4fb6-4153-cc3f-12d2020a1f7d/oauth2/token
```

Error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \
'client_id' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'client_secret' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

o/s: windows 10

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just remove two backslashes `\ ` that escape spaces. Probably a leftover of copy/paste.

Comment: Even after removing the slashes it gives me error curl: (6) Could not   resolve host: grant_type=client_credentials
'client_id' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'client_secret' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Remove **both** backslashes.

Comment: Did removed both

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: windows command line

Comment: Please add `cmd` and `windows` tags.